# How to pass array or object from JS to Rust for WebAssembly

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

Is it possible to pass array (String array) or object from JS to Rust?
This code compiles without errors, but does not work.

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Input {
    array: Vec<String>,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn array_length(input: &Input) -> usize {
    input.array.len()
}
```

I also tried [serde-wasm-bindgen](https://crates.io/crates/serde-wasm-bindgen), but still doesnt work.

WebAssembly does not expect to receive array or object from JS?

Comment: _How_ doesn't it work? How are you calling it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsValue from wasm_bindgen to send arrays between JS and Rust.

```rust
pub fn rotate_cube_colors(cube_colors: JsValue, instructions: JsValue) -> JsValue { 
   let cube_colors: Result<[CubeColor; 27], serde_wasm_bindgen::Error> =
        serde_wasm_bindgen::from_value(cube_colors);
   
   // More logic goes here...

   let response = JsonResponse {
        error_message: None,
        data: Some(cube_colors),// cube_colors is an array
    };

    let json = serde_json::to_string(&response).unwrap();
    return JsValue::from_str(&json);
}
```

And then call it from React like:

```js
export const rotateCubes = (
  prev: CubeColor[],
  rotation: {
    cube_index: number;
    axis: "X" | "Y" | "Z";
    direction: "Forwards" | "Backwards";
  }
) => JSON.parse(rotate_cube_colors(prev, [rotation])).data;
```

Full repo can be found here: https://github.com/eriktoger/rubiks_cube

Comment: To not have to parse the result you can return serde_wasm_bindgen::to_value(&response).unwrap() from rotate_cube_colors